# Angular.js and Node.js: Seeing an OPTIONS and one POST Request in Firebug but two POST Requests in Node.js

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, mongoose, mean-stack

To make a `POST` request with a Body full of JSON Data as Payload I use:

`$http.post('http://westeros:9000/model/create/', theBody).success(function(retData, status, headers, config){....});`

I am seeing this in Firebug:

[image: XSSR]

In Node.JS I am seeing two POST requests being made when I use:

`console.log(req.method);`

Interesing: One Payload (Body) is empty and one is as expected. I really would like to know if somebody has seen this issue or if I might have a bug elsehwhere.

Comment: Preflight request are sent by browsers regardless what library/framework are you using to make the requests. What is doing mongo here ?, you are logging all requests or something like that ?

Comment: I understand I will rephrase my question then. Problem is: Express routes the OPTIONS request to Mongoose as well and I am seeing two MongoDB requests, one with and one without `req.body` payload.